# Date informations by worksheet in MS Visio 2010

Tags: visio

I have a Visio Workbook with multiple Worksheets. I included a Date modified and a Date created field to each Worksheet, but it seems to be for the entire Workbook.

Is there a way that each Worksheet has its own date related information.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer from microsoft support.

First, I was wrong by saying I had Worksheets in a Workbook, Visio doesn't treat it that way (only Excel). It is really one whole document.

So to answer my question, NO, I can't have a Date field that is updated by PAGE only.

I possible solution would be to give each page his own Visio document.